# Howto disable client script block server side (asp.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dynamic-script-loading

I have js script block (very long one that does editing capabilities to an invoice page).

I want to enable/disable this functionality on the server-side. First thing popped up on my mind was to say runat="server" to the  tag, and set visible=true/false to asp.net, thinking asp.net does not render the HTML for non-visible items, so the block wouldn't load at all, which was what I wanted. But I quickly realized that saying runat="server" to client-side code was a real bad idea :)

What ar emy options, besides loading script from client side. Cuz I have other buttons that come from the server-that will enable dieable too ... If I use js for them the code will be ugly ... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this trick

```
<asp:Literal run="server" id="MyScriptBlock" EnableViewState="false">

     here type what ever you like

</asp:Literal>
```

and just make Visible or not the MyScriptBlock

Comment: literal renders to <span> .. do you mean wrapping script block with some other tag right .. I was thinking the same .. thanks a lot

Comment: @Emre literal not render to span ! They are empty, that why they called literal. try it, I have try it and its working.

Comment: yes it is .. but i used a placeholder instead... but thanks for the info .. thanks a lot :)

Comment: Using a literal gave me a compile error: "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal' does not allow child controls". But the PlaceHolder worked for me. Thanks.